# What is special about this sentence?

Tags: pattern

What is special about this sentence?

> Sphinx drove my quick Jag, "Blaze", FTW.

This riddle is probably too easy for this crowd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can make out, it's

> a pangram.

For those who don't know what this is:

> Pangrams are words or sentences containing every letter of the alphabet at least once; the best known English example being "A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".

Comment: Very good, that didn't take very long :-)

Comment: thanks, i just learnt about them a few days ago so that's the first thing that clicked! :P :)

Comment: It's an unpublished one, since I wrote it. You are one of the first in the world to see it, lol.

Comment: Its just that a few days back i was researching on them reading all examples and trying to make a few, so the moment i saw it i realized its a pangram

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what a pangram is, I had to search it up.

Comment: That's good advice....I'll make an edit